# UWP Application Crash in Windows.UI.Xaml.dll

Tags: c#, .net, crash, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm porting a WP app to UWP having one page showing mainly multiple images (showing a map) within the Canvas of an ItemsControl.
I'm using the manipulation  and pointer wheel events on the canvas and data binding with data templates/template selector - and everything works fine.
Unless sooner or later the app crashes in Windows.UI.Xaml.dll while I'm moving or scaling using Manipulation events:

[image: Exception dialog, call stack and disassembly]

[image: Thread list with thread description throwing the exception]

The crash always happens in CInteractionManager::ProcessManipulationInertiaInteraction (). The behaviour on x86 (PC) and ARM (WP10 phone Lumia 950) seems to be the same. My own c# code never appears in the call stack.

Here my question: Where should I look for the crash cause, or does someone know what I should check in my code?

Comment: Yesterday, when looking to some UWP examples, I realized that it seems to be common pratice to use Dispatcher.RunAsync to decouple lengthy computations from event handling. I did that in my ManipulationCompleted event - and the problem above was gone.

Comment: I have same problem. I used DispatcherTimer.Start() in Dispatcher.RunAsync. How to resolve this issue ? Please advice me.. GeorgM.