# Crash UWP app with dispatcher.RunAsync

Tags: uwp, crash

My UWP application sometime has crash. and It is not possible to debug at all. 
Now, I found some part of information.

first, The EventViewer show information. ( Sorry, All is Japanese. but Important information is ONLY "Windows.UI.Xaml.dll" has exception code 0xc0000005.

[image]

[Next is this information.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186456/uwp-application-crash-in-windows-ui-xaml-dll) . My Program also has crash in dispatcher.RunAsync. I confident This line has crash with my logging.

```
dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => action()).AsTask();
```

in my Dispatcher.RunAsync. I used

```
private EventHandler<object> eh = null;

"in dispatcher.RunAsync"
DispatcherTimer dtimer = new DispatcherTimer();

eh = async (sender, e) => await WhenTimerStop(sender, new A_SwitchEvent());
dtimer.Tick += eh;
dtimer.Start();
```

**Question**

Should I not use DispatcherTimer in dispatcher.RunAsync ?
How to use DispatcherTimer ?? I do not have knowledge. without running on UI thread, DispatcherTimer cause error. then I used Dispatcher.RunAsync.

in my timer, I do not touch UI. SHould I use other timer ? What is recommend in UWP ?

Comment: You can use but what you want to update with timer

Comment: I just control serial port in "WhenTimerStop"....Crash does not happen always. but somtime it happend.. I do not know why... The line "dtimer.Start();" has crash.

Comment: Can you share the code how you added the timer?